# VMWare ESX 4.1 - Upgrade from 2000 to 2003 R2 gives STOP Error 0X0000000A during "installing devices"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vmware-esxi, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I am trying to upgrade a recently P2V'd server, but I get STOP Error 0X0000000A every time I try.. It always gets this STOP error when it is trying to install devices during the upgrade process. Any ideas?
[image: Stop error below]

Comment: Driver issue of some sort, which I'm sure you had guessed - is VMware Tools installed before trying to upgrade, and are there any junk virtual hardware devices that came in with the conversion that you can get rid of?

Comment: Just tried uninstalling vmware tools before install, same BSOD. I will check for junk hardware devices.. I was thinking about trying this: http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=419

Comment: That did not work. I cleaned all old drivers up.. Hmm..

Comment: I meant as far as any devices that VMware thought the device needed and carried over to the VM which can be nuked - USB or serial ports, extra SCSI devices, etc.

Comment: Where is the log?

Comment: Just take a look at the VM's settings - if it's got a bunch of junk it doesn't need, tear some out (maybe compare to a fresh default VM to get an idea of what's normal).

Comment: Have you performed a clean up on the P2Ved machine? To do this go to a CMD prompt and type SET DEVMGR_SHOW_NONPRESENT_DEVICES=1 and then DEVMGMT.MSC and then select Show Hidden Devices. Delete any old grayed out hardware. As well, uninstall any hardware-related drivers from the system.

Answer (score 2):

Probably a device driver, possibly one of the vmtools ones, did you update these before updating?

Comment: Yes. Should I uninstall vmware tools?

Comment: if you can, see if that's any more stable but I'd still suggest you add in the latest vmtools at some point.

Comment: that did not do it.. just tried that, same BSOD screen

Answer (score 1):

Could be a SCSI driver issue. Try switching to LSI before you do the upgrade. You do this by adding a second disk to the VM with id 1.1. Change the controller type for controller 1 to lsi. Let the vm boot and find the new devices. Now shutdown and change controller 0 to lsi. Try the upgrade again.

Comment: I already tried that, I get the same BSOD..

Comment: Are you upgrading from Windows or Booting from the Cd?